# What's considered a good way to share "global" variables inside a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

How can I easily refer to other directories in my module without explicitly relative paths (`../../../lib..`)?

I'm writing a node module and there are some global things I want to reuse in my module.
Most basically - I want to set the root path of the module as a 'global' so I can easily call other sources without using a lot of relative paths `../../` and things like that. It can cause messy code and it's easy to mistake or miss it if the project structure changes.

So I've seen a lot of options [in that post](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) and some other libraries for dealing with those kind of things (such as modules that give the root path - [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path), [rootpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rootpath), [rfr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfr) etc.) but they all refer to a base project/application and not to a module that's being used by others.

Setting a global is a bad idea, and I understood that an environment variable is also not such a good idea.

Is there a good practice for that thing? Maybe there's something I haven't found or heard of.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to avoid and what I'm looking for:

```js
// avoid things like that:

// ./lib/something/forthat/doit.js
var config = require('../../../config/project/type1/config.js');

// ./config/project/type1/config.js
module.exports = {
  msg: 'hi'
};


// find somethings like that:
// when the root path/require can be found in every location of the module
// and is relative to my app and not the app using my module.

// ./lib/something/forthat/doit.js
var config = require(rootPath + 'config/project/type1/config.js');
// OR
var config = rootRequire('config/project/type1/config.js');
// OR anything else

// ./config/project/type1/config.js
module.exports = {
  msg: 'hi'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the current directory path you can use the global variable `__dirname` any where in your nodejs project. Example : `console.log(__dirname)` write this into any file in your project and console would print the current directory path as string.
Or, You can use express-session module like;

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(session({myVar: 'abc'}));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
var sess = req.session;
console.log(sess);
});
```

Comment: it still doesn't solve the problem. `__dirname` will give me the path of the current executing file, so I can save it when the program starts, but I still don't have a good solution to share that variable (a file isn't a good option)

Comment: yes, creating a file with variables and prototypes is a good idea. you can access it by creating a new object and use it's properties or methods anywhere in your project.

Comment: oh, I thought you meant writing to an external file. you mean by setting them on the `global` scope? (global.myRootPath?) or requiring this variables file in every file?

Comment: I mean require this file to every new script file. otherwise if you want few variables to be available globally, you can use session module.

Comment: I will still have to call that file with relative path once in every file, right? (like `var cfg = require('../../global_variables_config.js')`) or I didn't understood you correctly?

Comment: `npm install express-session` use this module to store(set/get) variables in session to use them globally in your project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all..... relative paths doesn't create confusion at all. rather you can call it messy (if you want) and it is considered to be the best practice. But I can understand you too. That you don't like very messy codes. So for this situation you should serve that part/peice of code as static content. Hence easily you can access it with giving a very login tailing path. But remember this way is an alternate to relative path serving.

Comment: you're right about the confusion/messy, that's kind of what I meant. I didn't understood your suggestion. Can you give a little example of what you meant? That's what I've meant, to be clear: https://jsfiddle.net/fzhqf4of/